# Two styled divs next to each other [flexbox/ responsive]

Tags: html, css, flexbox, responsive, portfolio

I am working on my portfolio website and have an issue with it. I try to make two divs standing next to each other, with text and an image in it. This was easy, but making it responsive with flexbox is a pain in the ass.

[This is what I try to achieve with flexbox, but this is just with plain html and css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7jzoY.png)

The code I use it this (without flexbox, because I just don't get it right):

```css
#best_cases {
  height : 800px;
}

#first_case {
  width         : 650px;
  height        : 577px;
  float         : left;
  margin        : 95px 0 0 211px;
  border-radius : 5px 5px 0px 5px;
  background    : #1f2930;
}

#first_case h2 {
  margin-left : 67px;
  padding-top : 20px;
  color       : #ffffff;
  font-family : montserrat bold,
                arial,
                verdana;
  font-size   : 2.5em;
  /* 40/16 */
}

#first_case p {
  margin-left : 67px;
  padding-top : 8px;
  color       : #ffffff;
  font-family : montserrat light,
                arial,
                verdana;
  font-size   : 1.125em;
  line-height : 26px;
  /* 18/16 */
}

#first_case img {
  margin-top                 : 72.6px;
  margin-left                : 70px;
  border-bottom-right-radius : 5px;
}

#second_case {
  width         : 650px;
  height        : 577px;
  float         : left;
  margin        : 95px 0 0 191px;
  border-radius : 5px;
  background    : #1f2930;
}

#second_case h2 {
  margin-right : 67px;
  padding-top  : 20px;
  color        : #ffffff;
  text-align   : right;
  font-family  : montserrat bold,
                 arial,
                 verdana;
  font-size    : 2.5em;
  /* 40/16 */
}

#second_case p {
  margin-right : 67px;
  padding-top  : 8px;
  color        : #ffffff;
  text-align   : right;
  font-family  : montserrat light,
                 arial,
                 verdana;
  font-size    : 1.125em;
  line-height  : 26px;
  /* 18/16 */
}

#second_case img {
  margin-top                : 72.6px;
  border-bottom-left-radius : 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="best_cases">
   <div id="first_case">
    <h2>T3Qvi3w</h2>
    <p>Shop voor het kopen van <br />
     smartphone accessoires.</p>
    <img src="img/TeQview_small.png" alt="" width="580" height="auto" />
   </div>

   <div id="second_case">
    <h2>Studieplaen</h2>
     <p>De nieuwste manier om <br />
     te plannen.</p>
     <img src="img/Studieplanner_small.png" alt="" width="580" height="380px" />
   </div>
  </a>
 </div>
```

I hope you guys now what to do. I'll be very helpfull.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: using fixed value is not good with responsive .. you need to remove all the fixed value (margin,height,width,etc ) and use % instead, or let the content take the necessary spaces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flex box is a fluid container, so when you start putting fixed pixel widths on elements you're going to break it.  With flex box it's a better practice use percentages for padding and margin and use flex properties for controlling widths so that you let them be fluid.

For instance here is your basic set up, but using flex box with percentages for padding and margin, and flex properties for controlling alignment, justification, and sizing.

In production, you'd probably want to add media queries to control your font sizing because with this side-by-side layout when you get small enough your content won't fix the containers and you'll have display issues.

```css
#best_cases {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: no-wrap;
  width: 100%;
}

#first_case,
#second_case {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  flex-grow: 0;
  background: #1f2930;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

#first_case {
  text-align: left;
  margin-right: 1%;
}

#second_case {
  text-align: right;
  margin-left: 1%;

}

#first_case h2,
#second_case h2,
#first_case p,
#second_case p {
  color       : #ffffff;
  font-family : montserrat bold,
                arial,
                verdana;
  font-size   : 2.5em;
  padding: 2% 10% 5% 10%;
  /* 40/16 */
}

#first_case h2,
#second_case h2 {
  font-size: 2.5em;
  /* 40/16 */
}

#first_case p,
#second_case p {
  font-size: 1.125em;
  line-height: 26px;
  /* 18/16 */
}

#first_case img,
#second_case img {
  max-width: 585px;
  height: auto;
}

#first_case img {
  margin-left: 10%;
  width: 90%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}


#second_case p {
  text-align: right;
}

#second_case img {
  margin-right: 10%;
  width: 90%;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="best_cases">
  <div id="first_case">
    <h2>Abcdefg</h2>
    <p>Shop voor het kopen van smartphone accessoires.</p>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/580x380" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div id="second_case">
    <h2>Hijklmn</h2>
    <p>Shop voor het kopen van smartphone accessoires.</p>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/580x380" alt="" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply. I now know what I did wrong. I just started using flex so I have a lot to learn. Again, thank you.